# Change Icon color depending on value using mvc

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, glitch-framework

i have an issue with some code in Javascript mvc fake gym app, where i want to change the color of an icon depending on value inside a for loop but the color dosn't change. The icon changes when outside the for loop but does anyone know how i can arrange the code so the colour of the icon will change for each value inside the for loop

```
    ///Model
{
getTrend(id, weight) {
    const memberassessment = this.getMemberlist(id);
    const assess = memberassessment.assessments;

    for (let i = 0; i < assess.length; i++) {

        if (memberassessment.startingWeight > assess[assess.length - 1].weight) {
            const color = "green";
            return color;
        } else {
            const color = "red";
            return color;
        }

    }

},


///controller
index(request, response) {
    const memberlistId = request.params.id;
    const loggedInUser = accounts.getCurrentUser(request);

    const viewData = {
      title: 'Memberlist',
      memberlist: memberStore.getMemberlist(loggedInUser.id),
      bmi: memberStore.getBmi(loggedInUser.id),
      weightClass: memberStore.getWeightClass(loggedInUser.id),
      idealBodyWeight: memberStore.isIdealBodyWeight(loggedInUser.id),
      getTrend: memberStore.getTrend( loggedInUser.id, loggedInUser.weight),

    };
   // logger.info("BMI" + bmi);
    response.render('memberlist', viewData);
  },

///view
<tbody>
      {{#each memberlist.assessments}}
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{weight}}
      </td>
      <td> {{chest}}   
      </td>
      <td> {{thigh}}
      </td>
      <td> {{upperArm}}
      </td>
      <td> {{waist}}
      </td>
      <td> {{hips}}
      </td>
      <td>     
        <a class="ui {{getTrend}} tag label"></a>
      </td>
      <td>
          <a href="/memberlist/{{../memberlist.id}}/deleteassessment/{{id}}" class="ui tiny red button">Delete
          <i class="icon trash"></i></a>
        </td>  
      <td> </td>    
</tr>
   {{/each}}   

  </tbody>

i want the icon to turn green or red using string
```

Comment: Once you do `return color;` in the loop, you exit the function and all the other loop turns are ignored. Also, you don't use `i` in the loop, which is strange. I think you should pass a parameter to `getTrend` instead of looping

Comment: yes in java i had a similar issue so i passed weight every time. but this dont allow me to pass parameters inside the html for loop

Comment: Why do you need the loop? It doesn't seem to be doing anything. From what I can see, you are checking if the member's weight recorded in the last assessment is less than the `startingWeight`. Isn't the if-else enough for that?